# Why is work done by non-conservative force around a closed path not zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, conservative-field

If work done by a conservative force in a closed loop is zero then why is the work done by a non conservative force not equal to zero. Since in both the cases the body moves in a closed path so the displacement must be equal to zero.

Comment: It may help to instead think of two distinct paths connecting two points. If the work done along path 1 isn't equal to the work done along path 2 you could travel along path 1 and then travel *backwards* along path 2 and the resulting work will be non-zero.

Comment: Non conservative forces like friction force causes energy dissipation during the closed round trip.